# Access DOM of an imported html document in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to reference an imported html document's DOM from inside a Polymer element that resides in said imported document. I've used Polymer's utility function `importHref()` to import the document. The app path/tree looks like this:

`index_page => imported_document => Polymer_element`

To access an element inside the index page I can do this:

```
var el = document.querySelector("#someElement");
```

To access an element inside a Polymer Element, I can do this:

```
var el  = Polymer.dom(this).querySelector("#someElement");
```

But, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to query the DOM of the `imported_document` from a Polymer Element that is inside of this `imported_document`. Using `document` returns null, and `Polymer.dom` is only for inside of Polymer Elements (I believe).

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I left the `<template>` tag out of the page I was importing, which was the source of the problem. It works now.